# Disabe android output thru HDMI when Slimport Hdmi cable is attached

Tags: java, android, linux

I want to make a ndk app that display something on screen using SurfaceFlinger. But I need android to do NOT mirror the screen of the phone on the TV when I atatch the Slimport cable .
How can I make android to do not mirror the screen on the tv , so I draw myself on hdmi using surfaceflinger?
Is there any build.prop or something setting?
Thank you!